# Query reverse ForeignKey lookup returns multiple objects

Tags: django, search

Okay, let's say I have two models. Person and Post.

Person has two fields, name and age. Post also has two, person and content.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    age = models.IntegerField(...)

class Post(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person, unique=false, related_name = 'posts')
    content = models.TextField(...)
```

Alright, so we have two people. Lisa Foobar (23) and John Baz (32). Lisa has 5 posts. John has only 2.

So in our views, to get the people by name or age we'd need  to do a query:

```
from django.db.models import Q

...

search = *insert your search query here*
people = Person.objects.all().filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(age__icontains=search))
```

So now when we search for "John" then John pops up, and also when we search '23' Lisa pops up, neat!

But what if we wanted to also search by post, and then display all the people who have a post with the contents of our search?

```
people = Person.objects.all().filter(Q(name__icontains=search) | Q(age__icontains=search | Q(posts__content__icontains=search))
```

This works nicely, however there is one catch. If the person has more than one post containing what you're searching for they'll appear multiple times.

So if Lisa has 3 posts containing the letter A, then she will appear 3 times in the query if you're searching for the letter A. Also for some reason if we simply search for Lisa she'll appear 5 times!

How can we avoid this?

Comment: How about adding `.distinct()`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Would you look at that, now Lisa only appears once! Post this as an answer so I can give you that sexy reputation by accepting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `.distinct()` so that the queryset only returns distinct results.